# тип string не работает в union

Tags: c++, struct, union

создаю в обьединение конструктор и пытаюсь использовать строки, но выдает ошибку на переменную типа структуры`material`

```
union {

    struct {

        string gold, bronze, silver, platinum;

    }material;

}jewel;
```

А вот и сама ошибка `error C2621: член 'main::$UnnamedClass$0x682e279a$23$::material' объединения 'main::$UnnamedClass$0x682e279a$23$' имеет конструктор копий`

Моя конечная цели инициализировать переменную `gold`, при условии что строки работают инициализация будет выглядеть так `jewel.material.gold = "asd";`

Comment: Ну и причем тут объединение, зачем оно  вообше  понадобилось?

Comment: Что-то у вас и `struct`, и `union` вообще не к месту. Может вам нужно `enum material {gold, bronze, ...}; struct jevel {material m;};`?

Answer (score 4):

Так нельзя. До с++11 есть явное ограничение https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union

> Unions cannot contain a non-static data member with a non-trivial special member function (copy constructor, copy-assignment operator, or destructor).

То есть, int можно, а string - уже нельзя.

После можно, но нельзя сделать в Вашем синтаксисе (либо я не знаю, как объявить конструктор для структур без имени.

В любом случае данная сущность немного странная и ее использование сильно ограничено. К примеру, нельзя писать в gold и читать с bronze.

Comment: На ссылке у вас говориться , что в стандарте ДО c++11 такое происходит.

Comment: Похоже на то...

Answer (score 2):

Объединение очень сложный предмет. Чтобы всё работало вы должный прописать конструктор по умолчанию. Чтобы объединение знало кого инициализировать первым.

Стандарт c++11 :

> [ Example: Consider the following union:
>
> union U { int i; float f;
> std::string s; };
>
> Since std::string (21.3) declares non-trivial
> versions of all of the special member functions, U will have an
> implicitly deleted default constructor, copy/move constructor,
> copy/move assignment operator, and destructor. To use U, some or all
> of these member functions must be user-provided. — end example ]

У вас нужно вручную вызвать конструктор для структуры `material` так :

```
# include <string>

union U {

    struct S {

       std :: string gold, bronze, silver, platinum;
    }material;
  U ():material{}{}
  ~U(){material.~S();}
}jewel;
```

Деструктор тоже вручную указывать надо какой элемент union нужно разобрать.